# How can I control username input in the ParseLoginUI?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using the ParseLoginUI to allow users to create accounts with, and sign in to, my app. As seen here: 
http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/25/login-love-for-your-android-app/

However, as it's currently configured, users can create usernames like "a b  " and Parse thinks that's perfectly fine. Most customizations with the ParseLoginUI can be done via `meta-data` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` but I haven't found anything in the documentation for controlling input. Is there a way to control this input? example: disallowing space characters

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you have three options:

> Customizing the Login Library
>
> There are three ways to customize the login library:
>
> Activity metadata in AndroidManifest.xml - This is most recommended
> because it allows you to customize the login experience without
> writing any code, and it makes the login experience consistent
> regardless which activity in your app launches ParseLoginActivity.
>
> In code with ParseLoginBuilder - If you love writing code to do
> everything.
>
> Overriding layout resource XMLs - This option is useful if
> you want to make significant changes to the look and feel of the login
> experience.

I would suggest the second method because the first doesn't seem to match your needs. Just check the String value when the User presses the "Sign up" button. Then return a toast which tells the user why is username is forbidden.

```
//In ParseSignupFragment.java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
    String passwordAgain = confirmPasswordField.getText().toString();
    //Other code

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(username);
    boolean found = matcher.find();
    if (username.length() == 0) {
        showToast(R.string.com_parse_ui_no_username_toast);
    } else if (found) {
        showToast(R.string.com_parse_ui_username_illegal_character_toast); //You must create this manually
    }
    //Rest of the method
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! And should this be in my module, overriding ParseSignupFragment, or should I edit the ParseLoginUI directly?

Comment: I am not exactly sure where you want to override what.. I think that you have ParseLoginUI included in your project as a library? Then it would be easier to just change it programmatically within your project. If you want to have some more changes it could be better to fork the project (at least locally). I hope I understood you right ;)